# How to create flow dynamically in MS bot using node

Tags: node.js, nodes, botframework

I want to create **N** no.of flow in MS bot like the first image. I have added the flow diagram (second image).

**Flow is:** When user press A from A, B, C & D, it will show A1, A2, A3 & A4 and when the user presses A1 it will show A11, A12, A13 & A14 and when the user presses A12 it will show A121, A122, A123 & A124 likewise flow continuous.

[image]

Below is the full flow
[image]

I have created this flow using following code. But the final code has more than 2000 lines. All are repeated function. So, I want to implement this with a minimum of code. Any idea?

Instead of A, B, C I need to use Issue, Request, Back, Access, Room type, Booking engine, Best Flexible Rate, Virtual Rate code, Inventory Count and etc. For understanding purpose, I used A, B, C.

Instead of A,B,C take these inputs for relationship

```
['PvtBank',GovtBank'] 

PvtBank=>['TBM','CUB','KVB'], 
GovtBank=>['IOB','CBI','BOB'], 
TBM => ['OUTSIDE INDIA','INSIDE INDIA'], 
INSIDE INDIA => ['DELHI','MUMBAI','PUNE'],
OUTSIDE INDIA => ['US','UK','CHINA'], 
DELHI => ['INDIA GATE','NEW DELHI'], 
US=> ['NEW YORK','LOS ANGELES'] and etc
```

.

```
bot.dialog('mainFlow', [
    function (session, results, next) {
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Whould you like me to taks about?", "A|B|C|D", { listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button });
    },
    function (session, results, next) {
        session.userData.TravelType = results.response;
        if (results.response.entity === 'A') {
            session.beginDialog('flowA');
        } else if (results.response.entity === 'B') {
            session.beginDialog('flowB');
        } else if (results.response.entity === 'C') {
            session.beginDialog('flowC');
        } else if (results.response.entity === 'D') {
            session.beginDialog('flowD');
        }
    }
]).endConversationAction("stop",
    "",
    {
        matches: /^cancel$|^goodbye$|^exit|^stop|^close/i
        // confirmPrompt: "This will cancel your order. Are you sure?"
    }
);

bot.dialog('flowA', [
    function (session, results, next) {
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Whould you like me to taks about?", "A1|A2|A3|A4", { listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button });
    },
    function (session, results, next) {
        session.userData.TravelType = results.response;
        if (results.response.entity === 'A1') {
            session.beginDialog('flowA1');
        } else if (results.response.entity === 'A2') {
            session.beginDialog('flowA2');
        } else if (results.response.entity === 'A3') {
            session.beginDialog('flowA3');
        } else if (results.response.entity === 'A4') {
            session.beginDialog('flowA4');
        }
    }
]).endConversationAction("stop",
    "",
    {
        matches: /^cancel$|^goodbye$|^exit|^stop|^close/i
        // confirmPrompt: "This will cancel your order. Are you sure?"
    }
);
```

Comment: From your question i can only think of making a rule engine which is like if rule a happend than rule b and if rule b than you execute rule c.i am not sure but may be this can be helpful ```https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rules```. using this one you can achieve such thing with minimal code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question is if the user clicks flow a then flow a submodule will work. Flow a submodule are a1, a2, a3, a4. If the user clicked flow a1 then it will show flow a1 submodules(a11,a12,a13&a14) likewise this will work. Your link is not worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following code snippet:

```
bot.dialog('mainFlow', [(session, args, next) => {
    let currentChoice = session.conversationData.TravelType;
    let promits = currentChoice ? [`${currentChoice}1`, `${currentChoice}2`, `${currentChoice}3`, `${currentChoice}4`].join(`|`) : `A|B|C|D`;
    builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Whould you like me to taks about?", promits, {
        listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button
    });
}, (session, args, next) => {
    session.conversationData.TravelType = args.response.entity;
    session.replaceDialog('mainFlow');
}]).endConversationAction("stop",
    "", {
        matches: /^cancel$|^goodbye$|^exit|^stop|^close/i
        // confirmPrompt: "This will cancel your order. Are you sure?"
    }
);
```

### update

> Okay. Take this inputs for relationship instead of A,B,C ['PvtBank',GovtBank'] PvtBank=>['TBM','CUB','KVB'], GovtBank=>['IOB','CBI','BOB'], TBM => ['OUTSIDE INDIA','INSIDE INDIA'], INSIDE INDIA => ['DELHI','MUMBAI','PUNE'], OUTSIDE INDIA => ['US','UK','CHINA'], DELHI => ['INDIA GATE','NEW DELHI'], US=> ['NEW YORK','LOS ANGELES']

So your requirement has explicit mapping relationships, so you can try to build a mapper object or array previously for mapping usage. Pls, refer to the following code snippet:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
let getRegion = () => {
    return {
        'OUTSIDE INDIA': getOutInd(),
        'INSIDE INDIA': getInInd()
    }
}
let getOutInd = () => {
    return {
        'US': ['NEW YORK', 'LOS ANGELES'],
        'UK': [],
        'CHINA': []
    }
}
let getInInd = () => {
    return {
        'DELHI': ['INDIA GATE', 'NEW DELHI'],
        'MUMBAI': [],
        'PUNE': []
    }
}
let map = {
    'PvtBank': {
        'TBM': getRegion(),
        'CUB': getRegion(),
        'KVB': getRegion()
    },
    'GovtBank': ['IOB', 'CBI', 'BOB']
}
bot.dialog('mainFlow', [(session, args, next) => {
    if(!_.isArray(session.conversationData.choices)){
        session.conversationData.choices = new Array();
    }
    if(session.conversationData.TravelType){
        session.conversationData.choices.push(session.conversationData.TravelType)
        session.conversationData.currentChoice = _.last(session.conversationData.choices)
    }
    session.conversationData.currentMap = session.conversationData.currentChoice? _.get(session.conversationData.currentMap,session.conversationData.currentChoice):map;
    let promits = _.isArray(session.conversationData.currentMap) ? _.values(session.conversationData.currentMap).join(`|`): _.keys(session.conversationData.currentMap).join(`|`);
    builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Whould you like me to taks about?", promits, {
        listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button
    });
}, (session, args, next) => {
    session.conversationData.TravelType = args.response.entity;
    session.replaceDialog('mainFlow');
}]).endConversationAction("stop",
    "", {
        matches: /^cancel$|^goodbye$|^exit|^stop|^close/i
        // confirmPrompt: "This will cancel your order. Are you sure?"
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working well. But, Instead of A, B, C I need to use Issue, Request, Back, Access, Room type, Booking engine, Best Flexible Rate, Virtual Rate code, Inventory Count and etc.

Comment: You scenrio still has a limited logic flow, I can't understand how you nest or boundless these Issue, Request, Back, Access, Room type, Booking engine.

Comment: Flow is same as what I have given in the flow diagram. But instead of A, B, C  I will use some other text. I expect a function which accepts an array of inputs like ['Bank','Access','Roomtype'], ['TBM','SBI','IOB'], ['IN','US','UK']. If the user presses Bank it should show ['TBM','SBI','IOB']. If the user presses SBI it should show ['IN','US','UK'] likewise it will continue the flow

Comment: To confirm, it not likes kinda smimple combination of these arrays, but should has some maps relationships? like Bank=>['TBM','SBI','IOB']=>, SBI=> ['IN','US','UK']. TBM=>somethind different?

Comment: Okay. Take this inputs for relationship instead of A,B,C  ['PvtBank',GovtBank'] PvtBank=>['TBM','CUB','KVB'], GovtBank=>['IOB','CBI','BOB'], TBM => ['OUTSIDE INDIA','INSIDE INDIA'], INSIDE INDIA => ['DELHI','MUMBAI','PUNE'],  OUTSIDE INDIA => ['US','UK','CHINA'], DELHI => ['INDIA GATE','NEW DELHI'], US=> ['NEW YORK','LOS ANGELES']